# AND and OR operator c

Tags: c, if-statement, operator-precedence

Hey i am working on a code and i stuck inside this if condition which is
   (Not a actual Code simplified for better understanding)

```
if(18&2==2)
do something;
```

this if condition not executing but if i write like this

```
if(18|2==18)
do something;
```

it executed normal

also when I,

```
printf("%d",18&2);
```

it gives 2 now i am so confused why the above if statement not executing, 
is it because of precedence ,please explain thanks.

Comment: I think it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yours is a [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) "error". The bit-wise operators have lower precedence than equality. Making `18 & 2 == 2` into `18 & (2 == 2)`, which is `18 & 1`. That last one obviously evaluates to 0, since 18 is divisible by 2.

In such cases, when you get "weird results". Start by adding parenthesis to make sure every operator operates on the operand you expect it too.

Answer (score 2):

The precedence of `==` is higher than `&`.
The expression:

```
if(18&2==2)
```

evaluated as follow:

`2==2` result in logical `true` (`1`).

`18&1` result in logical `false` (`0`);

Hence the `if` condition `(18&2==2)` evaluated as `false`.